# Add a list item that is different than the rest of a list

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a custom list adapter. The adapter is backed up by a `List<CustomObject> itemsOfList`
Works fine.
I need to sometimes show a list item that is a completely different layout than the rest of the items in the list and actually is just text (just like a "header" somewhere inside the list).
I did the following approach.
In my adapter's implementation of `getView` if the `position` passed as an argument is e.g. `7` then I return my custom view.
This works fine also except the following small problem:
I skip an item from my list.
In my `getView` the code does:

```
CustomObject o = itemsOfList.get(position);
```

to populate the items of my list.
But when the `getView` is called with position 7, I return my custom view. Then the next call is for position 8 but this means that I never do:

```
CustomObject o = itemsOfList.get(7);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't get it - I think you neglected to add a piece of information to connect the dots. From your description its entirely unclear how the 7 is motivated, i.e. why does your adapter return your custom view in response to an *index* in the item list - in my opinion it makes only sense to act on the *value* of an item, not on the index.

Comment: @Durandal:I want to add something like a header/banner in the 7th position

Comment: So in essence you put part of the model (the index where the header shall appear) into the adapter? Thats broken design - you should instead put a special value into the list and have the adapter act on that special value - problem disappears.

Comment: @Durandal:I am not sure I understand what you recommend. Could you post it as an answer and alternative approach with an small example?

Answer (score 1):

All the list are Zero based. Try `CustomObject o = itemsOfList.get(position-1);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a list, in java the List, Arraylist and Map Object types are zero based when it comes to using the get() method of the above mentioned objects. If you wanted to get the 1st item in a list it would be like so:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
String str = (String) list.get(0); //This gets the item named 1
```

what you were doing was something like:

```
String str = (String) list.get(1); //This gets the item named 2
```

But you expected it to return the item named 1, so the right way would be a position - 1 to get the item you desire.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be an item for each element to be displayed in the view to maintain an 1 to 1 relationship between items in the model and views displayed. This can be done either by having the adapter *lie* about the number of items (this can get complicated to implement) or simply have a special item that represents your headers.

The latter could be done this way:

```
// where the items are populated:
for (whatever) {
    itemsOfList.add(new CustomObject("item"));
}
// now add items for the header(s) to be displayed
itemsOfList.insert(headerIndex, new CustomObject("header"));
```

You can either have a special subclass of CustomObject (e.g. CustomHeaderObject) or simply a type flag in CustomObject. Lets assume the latter:

```
class CustomObject {
    String type;
    // other data members

    public CustomObject(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isHeader() {
        return "header".equals(type);
    }
}
```

This can be made prettier with constants, enums etc. Important point is that the CustomObject has a way to *tell how it needs to be displayed*.

```
 public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      CustomObject item = itemsOfList.get(position);
      if (item.isHeader()) {
          return new HeaderView(...);
      } else {
          return new ItemView(...);
      }
 }
```

The getView() method selects which kind of view it produces depending on the item *type*.

---

The alternative would be to *virtually* add the item to listOfItems by altering all methods related to item retrieval in the adapter. The adapter  needs to implements a mapping from adapter item count/index to header *and* items, e.g. in the adapter there are two sets of data, items and headers:

```
 listOfItems[Item1, Item2, Item3]
 headerIndex = 1
```

What the adapter exposes is the mixture of both:

```
 getView() [Item1, header, Item2, Item3]
```

For example the getItem() method in the adapter would need to do:

```
 public Object getItem (int position) {
     if (position < headerIndex) {
          // items before header are adressed normally
          return listOfItems(position);
     } else if (position == headerIndex) {
          // smuggles the header in
         return "header";
     } else {
          // items after header are adressed as position minus one
          return listOfItems(position - 1);
     }
}

public int getCount() {
     // there are as many items as in the list PLUS one header 
     return listOfItems.size() + 1;
}

// similar mapping for all other methods that address items/count/view
```

As you see this is already complicated with ONE header, if there are multiple headers it gets worse.

Comment: I like this approach you propose. I am was currently doing the latter you describe i.e. using "tricks" for the `position`. Funny thing although my approach seems to work, I have not added +1 in the `getCount`

Comment: Also another issue I have is that the views passed in `getView` are essentially reused so I have to also take that into account

Answer (score 0):

Itens starts with the 0 index. So the first is `itemsOfList.get(0)` and the last `itemsOfList.get(itemsOfList.size())`.
It's recommended to use an `Iterator` to iterator over a `Collection`. you can use the enhanced for loop too.
Keep in mind that the `List` interface does not have a iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other methods that you need to pay attention to (`getCount`, `getItem`, `getItemId`).

However, this might be somehow very difficult to extend if your special position (index 6) changes/is not determined always. Or if there are more special cases. I tend to construct a list of items in the adapter (`mAdapterList`) that is not of `CustomObject`, but has the special cases items included in it, so that the three `get*` methods will not have to account for anything special.

Based on your intention, however, this is what I would do:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    List<CustomObject> mAdapterList;
    Context mContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<CustomObject> items)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mAdapterList = items != null ? items : new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mAdapterList.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        if (position < 6)
            return mAdapterList.get(position);
        else if (position > 6)
            return mAdapterList.get(position - 1);
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        if (position < 6)
            return position;
        else if (position > 6)
            return position - 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (position != 6)
        {
            RegularItemViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() instanceof SpecialItemViewHolder)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.regular_item, parent, false);
                int arrayPos = (position < 6) ? position : position - 1;
                viewHolder = new RegularItemViewHolder();
                viewHolder.mRegularTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.reg_textview);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (RegularItemViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.mRegularTextView.setText(mAdapterList.get((position < 6 ? position : position - 1)).mText);
        }
        else
        {
            SpecialItemViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() instanceof RegularItemViewHolder)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.special_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new SpecialItemViewHolder();
                viewHolder.mSpecialTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.special_textview);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (SpecialItemViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.mSpecialTextView.setText("My special text");
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class CustomObject
    {
        public CustomObject(String text)
        {
            mText = text;
        }
        public String mText;
    }

    private class RegularItemViewHolder
    {
        public TextView mRegularTextView;
    }

    private class SpecialItemViewHolder
    {
        public TextView mSpecialTextView;
    }
}
```